# Concurrency thread group have different total samples in results with same configurations in jmeter

Tags: concurrency, jmeter

In jmeter, while using concurrency thread group,with same configurations I got different no. of total sanples in summary report. Can anyone explain why it happened?

I've below configurations:
Target Concurrency : 20
Ramp up time (sec) : 120
Ramp up Steps count : 10
Hold Target Rate time (sec) : 60

I've run the test twice, both time in summary report, i got 1704 samples and 1973 samples respectively.

Comment: Concurrency Thread Group will maintain concurrency for Threads not samples. Sample count may differ based on response time, latency, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JMeter waits for response from previous [sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) prior to sending the next request so the deviation is due to **response time**

- Higher response time - less results
- Lower response time - more results

If you want to always have **exact** amount of sample results - use [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) in `Total Executions` mode - this way JMeter will not run more samplers than you specify in the Throughput Controller.

Check out [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability) article for more information on the Throughput Controller and ways of defining how often different requests will be executed and how to precisely control your workload.